# Adding background image with CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I want adding background image with css but it did not work.Browser show me a blank page.

my application.css

```
home-body {
    background-image: url('/home.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;

}
```

file home.jpg located in a directory /public/home.jpg.

How fix?

Comment: instead of using `background-image: ` use only `background`.

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Did you mean to use .home-body as a class?

Comment: shouldn't you have home-body as a class or id? 
.home-body {...} or #home-body {...}

Comment: @leftside really have eagle eyes, I am sure this will help OP.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code. Use background instead of background-image and make sure that you have inserted the correct image path in url().

```
    html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
    .home-body {
    background: url('/home.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: This would not make a difference. Background is an alias for all 5 properties. background-color, background-image, background-position, background-repeat and background-attachment

Comment: This is works when I add width and height properties, but it looks bad not the entire screen, and on all sides of a white frame.why?

Comment: I have edited the answer let me confirm if this works

Comment: @138weare you have to define the `width` and `height` use `100%` and use `padding:0` for `body`  element.

Comment: How to stretch it over the entire width of the window?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an external CSS file... make sure to link the image file relative to the CSS file. For instance

`-ROOT
  -css
    -file.css
  -background.jpg
  -index.html`

you would need:

`background("../background.jpg");`

because ".." takes you up one directory :)

Answer (score 1):

it may be caused by 3 problem

1- home-body is not a tag of html.so it should be id or class name of a tag.so you should use `.home-body` for class name and `#home-body` for id name.

2- you do not address the background image correctly.if you want to make sure, give the url as an absolute path to your image like `http://yoursiteUrl/public/image/image.png`

3- your css file is not loaded on your page.try to make sure it is loaded on your site correctly if it is loaded then the problem is first or the second part mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

very easy like this....

```
.play{
    background: url("media_element/play.png") center center no-repeat;
    position : absolute;
    display:block;
    top:20%; 
    width:50px;
    margin:0 auto;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    background-image: url('img-url');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat

}
```